# HTML5 - resize image and keep EXIF in resized image

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, exif

How can I resize an image (using an HTML5 `canvas` element) and keep the EXIF information from the original image? I can extract EXIF info from from original image but I don't know how to copy it to the resized image.

This is how I retrieve the resized image data to send to the server-side code:

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7);
```

For EXIF retrieval, I'm using the [exif.js](https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js) library.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Working solution: [ExifRestorer.js](http://www.perry.cz/files/ExifRestorer.js)

Usage with HTML5 image resize:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) 
{
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
}
```

And main code, taken as part of HTML5 resizer from this page: https://github.com/josefrichter/resize/blob/master/public/preprocess.js (but slightly modified)

```
var reader = new FileReader();

//reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); //load data ... old version
reader.readAsDataURL(file);       //load data ... new version
reader.onload = function (event) {
// blob stuff
//var blob = new Blob([event.target.result]); // create blob... old version
var blob = dataURItoBlob(event.target.result); // create blob...new version
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); // and get it's URL

// helper Image object
var image = new Image();
image.src = blobURL;

image.onload = function() {

   // have to wait till it's loaded
   var resized = ResizeImage(image); // send it to canvas

   resized = ExifRestorer.restore(event.target.result, resized);  //<= EXIF  

   var newinput = document.createElement("input");
   newinput.type = 'hidden';
   newinput.name = 'html5_images[]';
   newinput.value = resized; // put result from canvas into new hidden input
   form.appendChild(newinput);
 };
};
```

Comment: Would you create a GitHub repo for your ExifRestorer.js file and add a license so others can use it? Or would you explicitly state the terms under which others may use the code in your answer here?

Comment: @KennyEvitt You can use code as you like. I dint create it, I just joined several parts of different codes together.

Comment: @MartinPerry - It works perfectly with my code - I do some canvas image manipulation - then I am able to restore data. However I would like to overwrite image exif orientation value. Once I rotate image with canvas -  exif orientation remains incorrect. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Thanks for ExifRestorer.js. Lovely script! <3

Comment: To make ExifRestorer.js work with file types different than jpeg it's necessary to replace the occurrencies of `'data:image/jpeg;base64,'` in the library with `/data:image\/\w+;base64,/`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [copyExif.js](https://gist.github.com/tonytonyjan/ffb7cd0e82cb293b843ece7e79364233).

This module is more efficient than Martin's solution and uses only Blob and ArrayBuffer without Base64 encoder/decoder.

Besides, there is no need to use [exif.js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) if you only want to keep EXIF. Just copy the entire APP1 marker from the original JPEG to the destination canvas blob and it would just work. It is also how [copyExif.js](https://gist.github.com/tonytonyjan/ffb7cd0e82cb293b843ece7e79364233) does.

## Usage

demo: https://codepen.io/tonytonyjan/project/editor/XEkOkv

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/jpeg" />
```

```js
import copyExif from "./copyExif.js";

document.getElementById("file").onchange = async ({ target: { files } }) => {
  const file = files[0],
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.drawImage(await blobToImage(file), 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.toBlob(
    async blob =>
      document.body.appendChild(await blobToImage(await copyExif(file, blob))),
    "image/jpeg"
  );
};

const blobToImage = blob => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const reader = new FileReader(),
      image = new Image();
    image.onload = () => resolve(image);
    reader.onload = ({ target: { result: dataURL } }) => (image.src = dataURL);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
};
```

Comment: I have made some changes in the above code as I required.
Now that the image is rotating I want to set "Orientation to 0", can you help me?
and I cant use "ctx.transform" because I want "Blob object" at the end.

Comment: Hi @mangeshbhuskute I made another version of `copyExif.js` to copy all EXIF fields but only writes to "orientation" field to "1". Can you try and see if it sovles your problem? https://gist.github.com/tonytonyjan/ffb7cd0e82cb293b843ece7e79364233#file-copyexifwithoutorientation-js

Answer (score 1):

It looks my code is used in 'ExifRestorer.js'...

I've try resizing image by canvas. And I felt that resized image is bad quality. If you felt so, too, try my code. My code resizes JPEG by bilinear interpolation. Of course it doesn't lose exif.

https://github.com/hMatoba/JavaScript-MinifyJpegAsync

```
function post(data) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", "/jpeg", false);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    req.send(data.buffer);
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(e){
            MinifyJpegAsync.minify(e.target.result, 1280, post);
        };
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas generates images with 20 bytes header (before jpeg data segments start). You can slice head with exif segments from original file and replace first 20 bytes in resized one.