# Canvas image produces awful color shifts

Tags: image, firefox, canvas, html5-canvas, filereader

Canvas image produces awful color shifts in Chrome and Firefox (Mac) when saved to disk or uploaded to server. Safari has faithful color. Examples below + JSFiddle to reproduce with original image. Notice how the subject's face becomes very orange.

http://jsfiddle.net/E4yRv/141/
:: Includes step-by-step with sample images on how to reproduce

Code Excerpt:

```
    canvas.ondrop = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
        reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var img = new Image(),
            imgStr = event.target.result,
            imgData = context.getImageData(0,0, context.width,context.height);
        state.innerHTML += ' Img source dropped in: <a href="' +
            imgStr + '" target="_blank">save image</a><br />';
        img.src = event.target.result;
        img.onload = function(event) {
            context.height = canvas.height = this.height;
            context.width = canvas.width = this.width;
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            state.innerHTML += ' Canvas img drawn: <a href="' + canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0) + '" target="_blank">save canvas</a> <br />*add .jpg extension when saving';
        };
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    return false;
};
```

When canvas draws the image in the respective browser the color renders to match the original. However, if the image is saved to disk locally and viewed in Photoshop (the only program that knows how to true handle color) the colors have shifted! Same occurs if viewing the saved file in a different browser.

Inspecting the images in photoshop, none have an embedded color profile. However, there is some translation of color that has occurred! It does not appear to be a case of misaligned profile or missing profile.

[image: Chrome Example]

[image: Firefox Example]

[image]

I have produced a detailed JS-Fiddle below on how to reproduce the issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/E4yRv/141/

Comment: Can you provide an image that you have this issue on for us to test with?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara test image is here: https://i.imgur.com/1UAqEU4.jpg

Comment: The test image is also available in my test here: http://jsfiddle.net/E4yRv/141/

Comment: Ah, must have missed it. I'm trying it on my end, and it doesn't look any more orange in Firefox than Safari like it does in you screenshot. How are you comparing them? Does it look orange if you open the image directly in Firefox, or only when drawn to a canvas? Does it look orange on the canvas, after saving it, or both?

Comment: Save the canvas element to disk and open it in Photoshop. If you create the canvas image in Firefox, it looks the same on screen. If you save the image (to server or local disk) and look at it in Safari the colors will have shifted. It's not a problem with Safari's color rendering its with the actual image data, opening the image in photoshop will show you the colors have shifted.

Comment: As I state in the question "When canvas draws the image in the respective browser the color renders to match the original. However, if the image is saved to disk locally and viewed in Photoshop (the only program that knows how to true handle color) the colors have shifted! Same occurs if viewing the saved file in a different browser."

Comment: Hmm, the difference seems much more subtle on my end. I did some analysis on the files with ImageMagick, and it looks like the only major difference is Safari is adding a new color profile to the meta data, but Firefox (and presumably Chrome) are simply discarding the information. [This question might be of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297120/html5-resize-image-and-keep-exif-in-resized-image).

Comment: Yes once drawn to canvas, the browser will already have decoded the image, discarding any ICC profile, so that only raw pixels remain in it. When you do `toDataURL('image/jpeg')`, you are **re-**compressing your pixels (adding more jpeg artifacts, which won't occure with png output) and the browser will use a default rgb ICC. So the resulting image has nothing to do with your original one anymore. You could try to include the ICC afterwards with some EXIF library, but anyway, your pixels won't be the same. To get the exact same output, don't use a canvas but only the FileReader.

Comment: Ps: the actual image you sent has a "Camera RGB Profile" ICC, certainly from an iphone. Here is the same without ICC : http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky7nw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the similar color shift phenomenon in browser recently, and the translation of color in the human face can be reproduced by the JSFiddle code. After some research and thanks to the suggestion provided by Alexander O'Mara (the color profile in image), here is my conclusion:

The phenomenon should be caused by the embedded color profile in the sample image. If you open the original image in photoshop, it will show a warning window, which indicates that the color profile doesn't match the current used color gamut, and three options can be chosen:

1. use embedded color profile (in short, let's call it ref_ICC)
2. convert the color to the current used color gamut (after the conversion, a new ICC, i.e., the con_ICC, will be embedded in the resulting image)
3. ignore the color profile

After saving the three images by choosing the respective options, let's open them in some image viewer. I use XnView to check if any color profile (ICC) is embedded in image, and use Photoshop to check the RGB histogram. The result is:
(the downloaded* stands for the image obtained by the JSFiddle code of canvas.toDataURL)

```
          | option 1 | option 2 | option 3 | downloaded*
histogram | ref_hist | con_hist | ref_hist | con_hist
ICC       | ref_ICC  | con_ICC  |    X     |    X
```

In a viewer (FastStone, for example) which doesn't care about the color profile (ICC), the displayed RGB value only depends on the histogram. So the original image (option 1) looks different from the downloaded one, in which the histogram seems to be converted by the browser in a way similar to the photoshop does for option 2. On the other hand, the image pairs of "option 1 & 3" and "option 2 & downloaded" show the same displayed value.

If the images are viewed in photoshop, then the three images (option 1 & 2 & downloaded) show the same displayed value. And as a final comparison, the  displayed value of the downloaded image is the same in FastStone and Photoshop, while the original image shows different displayed value in these two viewers.