# Reading JPEG file to retrieve orientation information

Tags: javascript, image, exif

I've been researching ways to retrieve orientation information from a JPEG file in pure JavaScript.

An excellent way to get this information is outlined in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32490603/4936905). Essentially one reads the entire file using `readAsArrayBuffer` and then processes it for the required information.

However, is it really necessary to read the *whole file* to retrieve EXIF information? Is there an optimization whereby one can read a subset of bytes when doing this?

For instance, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25955045/4936905) seems to suggest the first 20 bytes are good enough for the job. However, the [former answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32490603/4936905) writer himself asserts that he removed the `slice` statement because sometimes the tag came in after the limit (he had originally set it to 64KB, i.e. `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice(0, 64 * 1024));`)

So what's a rule of thumb one can use when programming this sort of a thing? Or does one not exist at all? I want to write code where performance doesn't get heavily affected by the size (in bytes) of file uploaded by a user. That is my goal.

*Note: I've tried Googling this information as well, however haven't found anything meaningful.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till a more seasoned expert chimes in, I've settled for `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice(0, 128 * 1024));`.