# Chromium Update "Respecting" Image Orientation Causing Issues with JPEG Uploads

Tags: javascript, css, image, cross-browser, exif

Last year I found an old [JS function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297120/html5-resize-image-and-keep-exif-in-resized-image/28597771#28597771) by [hMatoba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4511232/hmatoba) from a previous [question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28597771) that allows client-side resizing of JPEGs before uploads. This is very useful when EXIF data is needed on the server-side, and when images larger than a certain size are not needed.

This worked very well until Chromium's [switch](https://paul.kinlan.me/correct-image-orientation-for-images-chrome-81/) to respecting EXIF image orientation, this library now creates images that cut off part of the image. See here for an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTMQe.jpg. The library continues to work fine in IE (which is a bit useless in 2020...), but fails in Chrome and Edge (Chromium).

I feel like the issue is when the image object is created in the function and loaded with file data, there's a conflict between what the browser presents as "width" and "height" and what the EXIF data shows. Unfortunately, I can't figure out exactly where the fix needs to be implemented. Anyone care to help, or know if an alternative?